# jQuery detect broken image fires too late

Tags: jquery, html, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to detect broken images in jQuery, in which case I want to remove them and replace by it's alt text.
I'm using following code I found here on SO;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.logoimg').error(function() {
        $(this).unbind("error");
        $(this).parent().prepend("<strong>"+$(this).attr("alt")+"</strong>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
    //...
}
```

This works fine in FF.

In Chrome however, the browser still shows a square indicating a broken image.
It seems as if the `error` event fires too late to detect the broken image.

Can I have it fire sooner? Is there something else wrong with the code?

**[Edit]** Added a solution below. Anyone able to explain this earns solution to this question.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the live site?

Comment: If you inspect the DOM, has the `img` element been removed?

Comment: @Liam unfortunately I can't due to company sensitive information. I will try to provide a complete JSFiddle

@Alex, the `img` element is still in the DOM when inspecting in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the problem by elimination. It's not where you would think.
Under my script tags, I had a Google Ads code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_javascript.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");GS_googleEnableAllServices();</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","banner_1");
    GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","banner_2");
    GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","banner_3");

    GA_googleFetchAds();
</script>
```

It's the last call : `GA_googleFetchAds()` that kills it. Removing that call seems to solve my issue. Strangely.

I've now solved it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    GA_googleFetchAds();
});
```

Anyone with a reasonable explanation earns my eternal respect and gratitude.

Comment: It seems that the google fetch ads takes long and fires before your document is ready and because the document isn't ready your initial jquery waits, thus making you see broken images.

Comment: If my comment is actually correct I would suggest to remove document ready function, to prevent future pre-ready actions to delay your jquery code (untested suggestion).

Comment: So I've tried: 1. taking my error() out of docready. 2. taking GA_googleFetchAds() out of docready. 3. loading jQuery after Google Ads. 
Nothing seems to do the trick

Comment: Did you take your error() out of docready and left GA_googleFetchAds() in docready? If that yields the same result as both in docready, keep it like that (to prevent other code from loading before your error()) but if that doesn't get the same result as both in docready then you have some weird problem.

Comment: eventually, putting Google Ad stuff in docready yielded in no ads. So that wasn't really a solution. I solved it by manually adding an `onError="imgError(this)` attribute to each image tag. Now just to ignore the dirty HTML